Trying to show and filter Calcualted Column inside Search Web Parts using Managed properties and Refinable is not working
I have a site calculated column of type Date/Time named "PUETADateTime", which sum up the values from 4 other Date/time calculated columns (but only one of the 4 calculated columns will have value at any time), as follow:-

Now i want to show and sort this calculated column inside a search web part. so after i added the column >> i added it to a list and added some values >> then i did a re-index to the list and to the site 48 hours ago.
Now i checked the search service, and i found that there is a crawl property that has been created automatically, as follow:-

Now the site column did not get any managed property by default, so I did those 2 modifications:-

I added a managed property of type text (since the option to create a date/time managed property is disabled) named "PUETADateTimeOWSDATE", and i link it to the crawl property:-



I edited the "RefinableDate03" managed property >> and i link it to the crawl property, as follow:-


i did a re-index to the list and to the site, 24 hours ago.
but showing and sorting using the above managed properties did not work. here is my case:-

I am showing the manged property "PUETADateTimeOWSDATE" inside a column, and it will be showed as this format datetime;#2024-08-28T06:30:00Z which is not a valid date/time:-



I am showing the "RefinableDate03" inside a column which will be empty, as follow:-


when i tired to sort using the "PUETADateTimeOWSDATE" managed property, i get an error, which i think is valid since custom managed proprieties are not sort able:-

now when i tried to sort using the Refinable, i will not get any error, but the sort of the item will not get affected, either Descending or Asending.
so based on my above case, how i can show and sort my calculated column? what i am doing wrong?
